# Dihedral Group of even order

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, dihedral-groups

Prove for odd n, $D_{2n}$, dihedral group of 2n, isomorphic to $D_{n} \times Z_{2}$. Is it true for even n?

Comment: By the notation $D_n$, you mean the dihedral group of order $2n$?

Comment: @quasi yes I meant that.

Comment: Then, according to Wikipedia, the answer is "yes" if $n$ is  odd.

Comment: No this is not true in general, the dihedral group of order 16 is not isomorphic to the dihedral group of order 8 direct product $\mathbb{Z}_2$.  [Groups of order 16](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Groups_of_order_16).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

$$D_{2n}=\langle r,s\;|\; r^{2n}=s^2=1, \; rs=sr^{-1}\rangle$$
Consider $H=\langle r^2,s\rangle$ and $K=\langle r^n\rangle$.
Prove that $D_{2n}=H\times K$, $H\cong D_n$ and $K\cong \Bbb{Z}_2$.

**Counterexample for $n$ even**

$D_{16}\not\cong D_8\times \Bbb{Z_2}$

This can be done by considering the number of elements of order 2 in each group.